# PHP OOP: How to avoid exended classes inheriting class instance variables?

Tags: php, class, extends, instances

I am converting an existing web site from procedural PHP code to OOP. I'd like to set a Permissions class that contains information, such as $USER data, relevant to multiple extended classes (i.e. Database, Login, Validation, etc).

Am I able to set class instance variables for child classes (i.e. Database, Login, Validation) in the parent class (i.e. Permissions) via the magic method __construct(), and have them appear in each child class except the class they reference?

i.e. 'class Database extends Permissions' does not include Permissions::$db, otherwise a loop and error occurs.

Example code snippets appear below :

```
<?php
class Permissions {
  protected $db = '';
  protected $login = '';
  protected $val = '';

  protected $USER = array (); // i.e. $this->USER['id'], $this->USER['access-level']

  public function __construct() {
    $this->db = new Database();
    $this->login = new Login();
    $this->val = new Validation();

  // Code to populate $this->USER
  }
}

class Database extends Permissions {
  // Code
}

class Login extends Permissions {
  // Code
}

class Validation extends Permissions {
  // Code
}
?>
```

Is it better for each child class to call upon only the classes it needs to access? i.e.

```
<?php
class Permissions {

  protected $USER = array (); // i.e. $this->USER['id'], $this->USER['access-level']

  public function __construct() {
  // Code to populate $this->USER
  }
}

class Database extends Permissions {
  // Code
}

class Login extends Permissions {

  private $db = '';

  public function __construct() {
    $db = new Database();
  }

  // Code
}

class Validation extends Permissions {

  public function __construct() {
    $db = new Database();
  }

  // Code
}
?>
```

Comment: Inheritance doesn't work this way, or *shouldn't* work this way. Always ask yourself: *Is* `Validation` *a* `Permission`? *Is* `Login` *a* `Permission`? The answer is: no, they aren't. These classes have nothing to do with one another and shouldn't be in the same hierarchy to begin with. You also shouldn't be instantiating a `new Database` in every single classes' constructor. Learn about *dependency injection*.

Comment: Question answered! Appreciate the nod in the right direction.